# Get controls ClientID/UniqueID between DetailsView and UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, detailsview

I like to know how to get the ClientID/UniqueID of a control inside a Detailsview controls EditItemTemplate element and when DetailsViews changing to Edit mode and DetailsView is inside a AJAX UpdatePanel. Without UpdatePanel, during PostBack I can get the ClientID's control, but now with an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkboxTest" Text="CHECKBOX" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you see, the EditItemTemplate contains a Checkbox control. So i'm trying to get the  ClientID of this checkbox when Detailsview is changing to the Edit mode. I need this value for handling Javascript.

Catching the events ChangingMode/ChangedMode doesn't work; chkbox is null:

```
 void DetailsView1_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
            var chkbox = DetailsView1.FindControl("chkboxTest"); // <==  is null
        }
    }
```

Maybe i'm using the wrong event? Someone can give me a tip about this? Thanks.

Comment: Is that a typo in your ModeChanged event in FindControl, it's looking for chkxboxTest...? If that's your code then that could be the problem.

Comment: @Mantorok. sorry typo. But still null.

Comment: Ok, then try Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl.

Comment: Also check the RowType of Rows[0], if it's DataControlRowType.Header then you need to reference the next row.  Your code has also changed above, FindControl will not work directly under DetailsView1 as it only contains the Rows/Cells, so you need to drill down to the Cell that actually contains your checkbox and then call FindControl.

Comment: @Mantorok. Thanks for you reply. The first row isn't type header but DataRow. And using FindControl on row[0] or row[0].Cell[0] still null. :(

Comment: robertpnl, it might not be Cells[0], it may well be Cells[1], the best thing to do is perform a FindControl in debug, you want the actual cell that contains your control, when you've identified that you should be able to find the control.

Comment: robertpnl, see edits to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the best thing to do is implement a handler for **OnDataBound**, then do something like:

```
  protected void databound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
     {
        var control = DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("chkboxTest");
        if (control != null)
        {
           // Write some JS...
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mantorok. Thank you! This will solved my problem. During this event, the control will be found. Thanks for your time and replies!

Answer (score 0):

void DetailsView1_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
       var chkbox = DetailsView1.Rows[0].FindControl("**chkxboxTest**"); // <==  is null
}

Is the enboldened text a typo?

I haven't had much use of the DetailsView but make usre Rows[0] is not a header row, and are there any Cells under the rows? Like the GridView.

UPDATE: I'm assuming all you want to do is capture the control after the user has updated the items? Assign an event handler to OnItemUpdating and try the following:

```
protected void updating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   var control = DetailsView1.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[1].FindControl("chkboxTest");
}
```

Comment: Sorry typo, event changed but still null.

Comment: Hi @Mantorok. Your update info is usefull. It works... but the event ItemUpdating will be fired when the use hits the update link/button. And, i'm sorry to tell you, I like to get the clientID during the mode change to Edit so I can init javascript during the edit mode.

Comment: robertpnl.  Is your ModeChanged being fired at all? If it is then DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("chkboxTest") should suffice.

Comment: The ModeChanged event being fired yes. But no Control is found. But you give me the answer already :)